# Find and highlight closest matching value on a specific row in a multidimensional table in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have mutliple tables of data for salary based on disciplines and I'd like to find the closest matching salary based on the employee level and highlight the cell with conditional formatting. The two tables I have to begin with are **ProgrammingSalaryGridTbl** defined between A2:H7 and **ArtSalaryGridTbl** in A11:H15.

[image: SalaryGrids]

I have set up two conditional formatting rules one for each table:

[image]

The formula I am using is `=AND("Programming"=$K$2, ABS(C3-$M$2)=MIN(ABS(DROP($C$3:$H$7, 1)-$M$2)))`

At the moment it shows 2 entries when the salary in M2 is set to 22000. If I modify the function to include the Level defined in L2 to become `=AND("Programming"=$K$2, ABS(C3-$M$2)=MIN(ABS(DROP($C$3:$H$7, 1)-$M$2)))*($A3=$L$2)` nothing is highlighted.

If I change the value in H5 to match the salary at 22000 it is highlighted.

Is there a way to modify this formula to only give the closest matching salary to the salary in M2  if the Level in column A matches that in L2?

Comment: vlookup() and match() both have an argument controlling the matching behaviour. You might want to try those.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant solution but it is working and is relatively flexible when adding a new table through duplication.

However, it is not the best solution if a new Level is added, increasing the table row size, which would mean there'd be a lot of table re-creation or addition many conditional formatting rules - with the number of tables I have, deleting all but the first and then copy pasting works pretty well.

How the data now looks:

[image]

**Solution**

Add a conditional formatting rule for each row of the table:

[image: Conditional Formatting Rules]

The rules are now as follows:

`=AND($A3=$K$2, ABS(C5-$M$2)=MIN(ABS(DROP($C4:$H5, 1)-$M$2)))*("Junior"=$L$2)` Applies To: `=$C$5:$H$5`

`=AND($A3=$K$2, ABS(C6-$M$2)=MIN(ABS(DROP($C5:$H6, 1)-$M$2)))*("Mid-Level"=$L$2)` Applies To: `=$C$6:$H$6`

`=AND($A3=$K$2, ABS(C7-$M$2)=MIN(ABS(DROP($C6:$H7, 1)-$M$2)))*("Senior"=$L$2)` Applies To: `=$C$7:$H$7`

`=AND($A3=$K$2, ABS(C8-$M$2)=MIN(ABS(DROP($C7:$H8, 1)-$M$2)))*("Principal"=$L$2)` Applies To: `=$C$8:$H$8`

`=AND($A3=$K$2, ABS(C9-$M$2)=MIN(ABS(DROP($C8:$H9, 1)-$M$2)))*("Lead"=$L$2)` Applies To: `=$C$9:$H$9`

`=AND($A3=$K$2, ABS(C10-$M$2)=MIN(ABS(DROP($C9:$H10, 1)-$M$2)))*("Director"=$L$2)` Applies To: `=$C$10:$H$10`

A3 refers to the discipline which actually sits outside the table so when I need to create a new table I copy this along with the table and paste below, as can be seen with the Design table in the above image.

I then repeat this process for any new disciplines, the conditional formatting is copied automatically with the table and any non static cells in the conditional formatting formulas are updated to the new destination.